The compactness of Radon probability measure
Let X be a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Denote by $\mathcal{R}$ the space of Radon measures on X, and $\mathcal{P}$ the space of Radon probability measures on X.
In my book, it says that $\mathcal{P}$ is a compact subset of $\mathcal{R}$ with topology of weak convergence of measures. I know that when a Banach space X is reflexive, if Y $\subset{X}$ is closed and bounded, then Y is compact. However, I do not think $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive. So, how to prove $\mathcal{P}$ is compact?

Thank you for your comment. Here, what is the definition of $\delta_i$ ?

As X is compact now, I think they have a weakly convergent subsequence. Am I wrong?

Weak convergence in Banach space theory means something different than weak convergence of measures. Here, you can identify the space of signed Radon measures with the variation norm as the dual of $C(X)$ with the sup-norm (buy Riesz-Kakutani). Then, weak convergence of measures corresponds to weak* convergence, and the compactness of probability measures follows from Banach-Alaoglu.
